# How to set up Hive metastore off Redshift

Tags: hive, amazon-redshift, cloudera-cdh

I couldn't find a way to set up a metastore off Redshift for Hive. I am wondering if there is anyone who has tried this. Also since Redshift supports PostgreSQL, maybe it is possible. Please share if you have any experience.

I am new to Hive and am using CDH5.4.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Redshift is giving SQL interface already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift as DSS isn't suitable to store Hive meta store by definition. Use RDS service for that purpose.

Comment: Hi @yuri. What do yo mean by definition? Any references or links to the documentation that you can provide on this topic?